# Save html from element into a variable simple html dom parser

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, php-parser

I want to get the innerHtml from an element, with simple html dom parser.

For example:

```
$s = "      <div class="a">
                <p>I don't want this stuff</p>
                <div class="b">
                    <input type="button" value="testing">
                    <p>I want this stuff</p>
                </div>
            </div> ";

$html = str_get_content($s);
$ret = $html->find('div[class=b']);
```

Now ... I want to initialize another object, but with the html from $ret.

I've tried with $newSource = $ret[0]->save(), but it's not working. In their documentation it doesn't appear something about innerHtml or outerHtml, just innerText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation there is a way to [dump your dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_dump), maybe that can be used as wenn to dump just a part of your some.

```
echo $ret[0]; // this should return your dom fragment
```

if you want another object and `$object = $ret[0]` isn't what you're looking for, this could help:

```
$html = (string) $ret[0]; // convert to html
$newSource = str_get_content($html); // create new object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ret[0]->innertext
```

will give you the inner HTML of the element (even if it's called text, it's actually the whole html)

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I used the class but have you tried 
`echo $ret->plaintext;`

Comment: it's showing the plaintext, no html. I want to be able to reparse it, and it needs to be html.